# Change return type for Spring findBy*()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an interface that extends CrudRepository, and I'd like to change the return type of my `findByAge()` from `Employee` to the employee's name (String). How would I do this? Would I have to write a wrapper class that calls `EmployeeRepository.findByAge()` that pulls out the name?

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {

    // change this to return a List<String> (List of employee name)
    List<Employee> findByAge(int age); 

}
```

Comment: You'll find your answer here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Query Annotation

If you don't want to map anything you can make your own query using the `@Query` annotation.

It would look something like this:

```java
@Query( "SELECT e.name FROM Employee e where e.age = :age" )
List<String> findAllEmployeeNames(@Param("age") int age);
```

This would return something like this:

```json
[ "Ann", "Tom" ]
```

### Interface-based Projection

Or as mentioned in the documentation in the comments, you can use interface-based projection.

Interface:

```java
public interface NameOnly {
    String getName();
}
```

In repo:

```java
List<NameOnly> findByAge(int age);
```

This would return something like this:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "Ann"
    },
    {
        "name": "Tom"
    }
]
```

*So this doesn't actually return a list of strings like you asked. Also note that this can create ambiguity in signature if you also want to support findByAge for the Employee object. You can work around this ambiguity by appending the function name with an underscore, but generally I would only go for this option when you always want to return a certain object as a DTO, masking some members (like db id).*

### Mapping

You can of course always just get the objects and map them in your controller (/or service).

That would look something like this:

```java
@GetMapping("/employees/{age}")
public List<String> getEmployeeNames(@PathVariable Integer age) {
    return employeeRepository.findByAge(age).stream().map(Employee::getName).toList();
}
```

*This would return a list of strings similar to the first option.*

Comment: I like the query annotation approach best. Thank you :)

Comment: Code works, but I'm getting an error in my unit test. Any ideas what would be causing it? `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [SELECT e.name FROM Employee e WHERE e.age = ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement`

Comment: @Jon Check the version of Hibernate and the database dialect you are using. Try enabling debug logging for Hibernate and examine the generated SQL statement. `logging.level.org.hibernate=debug` or `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` might help. Compare the test with runtime...

Comment: If you are using a different db for your tests, make sure to set the right dialect in the test properties.